How to fix Pydantic "Default value is not JSON serializable" warning when using third-party annotated type? [non-serializable-default]
Pydantic supports annotating third-party types so they can be used directly in Pydantic models and de/serialized to & from JSON.
For example:
from typing import Annotated, Any

from pydantic import BaseModel, model_validator
from pydantic.functional_validators import ModelWrapValidatorHandler
from typing_extensions import Self

# Pretend this is some third-party class
# we can't modify directly...
class Quantity:
    def __init__(self, value: float, unit: str):
        self.value = value
        self.unit = unit

class QuantityAnnotations(BaseModel):
    value: float
    unit: str

    @model_validator(mode="wrap")
    def _validate(value: Any, handler: ModelWrapValidatorHandler[Self]) -> Quantity:
        if isinstance(value, Quantity):
            return value
        validated = handler(value)

        if isinstance(validated, Quantity):
            return validated

        return Quantity(**dict(validated))


QuantityType = Annotated[Quantity, QuantityAnnotations]

class OurModel(BaseModel):
    quantity: QuantityType = Quantity(value=0.0, unit='m')

This works fine, because we just annotated the Quantity type so Pydantic knows how to serialize it to JSON with no issues:
model_instance = OurModel()
print(model_instance.model_dump_json())
# {"quantity":{"value":0.0,"unit":"m"}}

But if we instead try to get the JSON Schema that describes OurModel, we get a warning that it doesn't know how to serialize the default value (the one it just successfully serialized)...
OurModel.model_json_schema()
# ...lib/python3.10/site-packages/pydantic/json_schema.py:2158: PydanticJsonSchemaWarning:
# Default value <__main__.Quantity object at 0x75fcccab1960> is not JSON serializable;
# excluding default from JSON schema [non-serializable-default]

What am I missing here? Is this a Pydantic bug, or do I need to add more to the annotations to tell Pydantic how to serialize the default value in the context of a JSON Schema?
Does anyone have a good workaround to easily include annotated third-party types as default values in JSON Schema generated by Pydantic?

Are you using Pydantic 1 or 2?

Pydantic 2.7.1 (see tags)

Would your quantity by astropy.units.Quantity by chance?

Yes, it is astropy.units.Quantity- but trying to keep the SO question as general as possible. : )

You can provide multiple annotations to Pydantic to help with schema generation, etc.
Below is a full example:
class _QuantityJson(BaseModel):
    value: float
    unit: str

def _validate_quantity(value: Any) -> Quantity:
    if isinstance(value, Quantity):
        return value

    if isinstance(value, dict):
        _qjson = _QuantityJson.model_validate(value)
        return Quantity(value=_qjson.value, unit=_qjson.unit)

    raise ValueError(f"cannot parse quantity from {value}")

_schema_quantity = _QuantityJson.model_json_schema() | {"title": "Quantity"}

def _serialize_quantity(quantity: Quantity):
    return _QuantityJson(value=quantity.value, unit=quantity.unit)

QuantityAnnotated: TypeAlias = Annotated[
    Quantity,
    Field(validate_default=True),
    PlainValidator(_validate_quantity),
    WithJsonSchema(_schema_quantity),
    PlainSerializer(_serialize_quantity),
]

Then you can use it in your model:
class Model(BaseModel):
    quantity: QuantityAnnotated = Field(default=_QuantityJson(value=0.0, unit="m"))

You need to use a _QuantityJson default value because the serializer is not used for the default value (maybe a Pydantic bug?). You can directly assign the default value, but any decent type checker will throw a warning, so I am using a Field with default.
Below is an example usage:
print(Model.model_json_schema())
print(Model.model_validate(dict(quantity=Quantity(3.2, "m"))))
print(Model.model_validate(dict(quantity=Quantity(3.2, "m"))).model_dump_json())
print(Model.model_validate(dict(quantity=dict(value=3.2, unit="m"))))
print(Model.model_validate_json(b"""{"quantity": {"value": 3.3, "unit": "m"}}"""))


Thanks! This looks good - I am working on wrapping astropy.units.Quantity. This is an intimidating volume of core_schema machinery I don't fully understand, but I'll see if I can get my head around it.

Does this solve the problem, though? I don't see an example where you're using a Quantity() as a default value in a JSON schema. I'll test this out and report back. Thanks for your help!

Re: Extending BaseModel I was following this blog post from late last year - inheriting from BaseModel seemed to yield significantly less boilerplate than doing all the core_schema bits myself.

Actually @Holt - I think the fact that you have used @dataclass decorators might be obscuring the behavior I'm trying to resolve - see here _type_has_config() has special-case handling for dataclass types, so they work with encode_default()

@bjmc That blog post is pretty bad. Either you use model_validator in your actual model to validate a field, or you use a completely standalone class or function combined with Annotated. You don't need all the boilerplate if you use Pydantic built-in validator, see https://docs.pydantic.dev/latest/concepts/validators/#before-after-wrap-and-plain-validators, but in this case you cannot get the JSON schema as far as I know.

@bjmc This code does work, I've run it, I don't know what you mean by "using a Quantity() as a default value in a JSON schema" - If you want to change the JSON schema, you can easily do it in __get_pydantic_json_schema__. The behavior of the code is not related at all to dataclass, I'm using a slightly different version of that code with astropy.units that are definitively not dataclass and it works perfectly. If you have trouble adapting this to your actual code, you should provide more details, in particular on what Quantity actually is.

What am I missing? I get an exception trying to implement your suggestions Could you edit your answer to include a complete runnable example that shows how to use this in a Pydantic Model with a default value? For example line 102 in my paste: quantity: AnnotatedQuantity = Quantity(5, 'seconds')

@bjmc Ah yes sorry, the issue is the default value, you need to use Field with a default factory, I'll update the code.

@bjmc The same default issue will occur with astropy, and I don't really know how to fix it asside of using Field. If you're using astropy, you can directly use Quantity(value) instead of Quantity.parse and is_equivalent is already part of astropy.units.Unit. Everything else is basically identical in my actual code for astropy, except that I do not handle the dictionary value/unit case.

Thanks, @Holt - this is a lot of good information! Maybe I should have been clearer in the question - this was really narrowly scoped to the problem with the default value. Everything else works correctly using astropy Quantity and the BaseModel style annotations.

Using default_factory with a callable avoids the warning, but we still don't get the default value included in the JSON Schema output.

thanks for all your help - you've given me a bunch of things to chew on. Unfortunately, I can't accept this as an answer because I don't see that it's actually solved the problem - the default value still doesn't appear in the JSON Schema specification the way I'd hoped. I think this might be a bug in Pydantic.

@bjmc If you want to specify the default, you can simply update __get_pydantic_json_schema__ - I misread your question at first, which is why I did not include the default and simply provided the way I do it for astropy. This is much more convoluted than your version because it allows writing stuff like {"quantity": "3m"} which requires custom parsing. I will update the answer with code limited to your version.

@bjmc I've updated my answer to remove boilerplate code and only focus on the way you want it (i.e., a dict with value/unit in JSON). The code generates proper JSON schema (with default), will properly parse and serialize JSON. I used a PlainValidator instead of an annotated model as you did because I don't think that's the way it should be done - Pyright goes a bit crazy with _validate not returning a QuantityAnnotations in your example and I think he's right, but that's up to you.

Yeah, this is pretty close! It's disappointing that the default is a _QuantityJson() instance instead of a Quantity() but passing Field(validate_default=True) is a clever hack to transform it into a native Quantity object.


because the serializer is not used for the default value (maybe a Pydantic bug?).

Yes, I think this is a bug. Let's see if the Pydantic maintainers agree.
Anyway, thanks for your help - what you've got here is probably about as close as it's possible to get without upstream changes.

Can I ask, why are you so against the idea of using a BaseModel subclass as an annotation? It seems to work and there's lot of examples (maybe old Pydantic 1?) of that style online - what's the drawback?

@bjmc I don’t really like the idea of modifying the model itself in the validator, which is what your model do and what pyright warn against. When the validator is used to modify fields, etc., or to validate (not convert) the model, it makes sense, which is what is done in most Pydantic 1 model (e.g. in your example you could use field validator in the main model to convert the quantity field).
